# How can I extract filtered data from a table?

Tags: r, datatable

Is there any way for me to filter a data table into a more specific table?

for example if I had a data set that has multiple entries, and I was only interested in one value, such as the people who responded with yes on a given year. let's say 2010 and "yes" response. what function would be best for a scenario like that?

if there is a way to write a conditional statement for such parameters, I would like to know how.

I have tried:

```
table(dataset$year == "2010", dataset$response == "yes")
```

and what I got was a truth table

Answer (score 0):

use dplyr filter()

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% filter(year == "2010", response == "yes")
```